# What are Oracle's old-syntax join equivalents of these queries?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

What are the equivalent joins written in the Oracle's old join syntax of these queries?

```
 SELECT first_name, last_name, department_name, job_title
    FROM employees e RIGHT JOIN departments d
    ON(e.department_id = d.department_id)
    RIGHT JOIN jobs j USING(job_id);
```

-->106 rows returned

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, department_name, job_title
FROM employees e RIGHT JOIN jobs j
ON(e.job_id = j.job_id)
RIGHT JOIN departments d
USING(department_id);
```

--> 122 rows returned

Comment: *Why* would you want to rewrite standard joins as old-school, implicit joins?

Comment: It is because, unfortunately many developers are not good at the new syntax in the company I work in. So I need to learn the old syntax well. 

I saw these queries at another question, tried but could not find the equivalents with the old syntax.

Comment: @oramas . . . Teach the developers the new syntax.  It has been standard for over two decades and it is time for your developers to learn it.  It really isn't very hard to learn -- and I can say that as someone who had to learn it.

Comment: I know, but at the end, I need to know the old syntax well, to maintain the previously written codes as well. So, any answers will be appreciated

Comment: @GordonLinoff - It is quite hard to teach the other developers the modern syntax, if the "teacher" doesn't know the old syntax, is it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this (for the first query) - making explicit the fact that a multiple join is, by definition, an iteration of joins of two tables (or more generally "rowsets") at a time. Think of it as "using parentheses explicitly".

```
select first_name, last_name, department_name, job_title
from   (
         select first_name, last_name, job_id, department_name
         from   employees e, departments d
         where  e.department_id (+) = d.department_id
       ) sq
   ,   jobs j
where  sq.job_id (+) = j.job_id
;
```

This can be rewritten (perhaps) using a single SELECT statement, with more WHERE conditions - but the query will be less readable; it wont' be quite as clear what it is doing.

Comment: I couldn't see a way to write it without an inline view, which is interesting in itself. I managed to rewrite it using ANSI left join syntax (my standard first step in refactoring right joins) but it still needed bracketing to persevere the join precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Respectively:

```sql
SELECT first_name,
       last_name,
       department_name,
       job_title
FROM   employees e,
       jobs j,
       departments d
WHERE  e.job_id (+) = j.job_id
AND    e.department_id = d.department_id (+);
```

and:

```sql
SELECT first_name,
       last_name,
       department_name,
       job_title
FROM   employees e,
       departments d,
       jobs j
WHERE  e.department_id (+) = d.department_id
AND    e.job_id = j.job_id (+);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a01e8963b41a1dea64cf9c01fafbb34c)*

However, please just use the ANSI join syntax. The old legacy join syntax is confusing to read and you will get errors from putting the `(+)` on the wrong side of the join condition and you should be teaching people how to use the less-confusing, "new" (its hard to call it new when its been around since Oracle 9i in 2001) syntax rather than reverting to old methods.

Comment: Hi MT0,
First of all, thanks a lot. But I'd like to ask something. What I know about the old syntax is, if I'm using right outer join, I put (+) to the left side. If I'm doing that for only one join, it works fine. But if there are two right joins as in my question, it fails. Because it looks like I should to like this "WHERE e.job_id(+) = j.job_id AND e.department_id(+) = d.department_id;". But you used them in different columns when you join the first two tables. Btw, the second one returns the same result, but first one returns 107 rows, while the old syntax returns 106

Comment: Let's just look at the first query. As the OP says, your solution does the wrong-side outer join between `e` and `d`. When you move the outer join marker to the other side and run the query, you will find that it returns a lot more rows, for the (obvious) reason that, if you look at it carefully, it cross-joins `d` and `j` and then it outer-joins the result to `e`. The translation to old Oracle syntax is not as simple as it may seem.

Comment: This was an interesting puzzle (and another reason to avoid right joins). The confusing right joins in the original query are driven from `jobs` and `departments`, so even though the outer join from `departments` to `employees` includes the 16 departments with no employees, outer joining from `jobs` to *that* implicitly excludes rows with no job_id, because even though it's an outer join we are driving it from `jobs`, and so effectively the OJ to departments becomes an inner join. You have to bracket it as in @mathguy's answer to preserve the precedence. Right joins are just evil.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Mathguy's answer, this is interesting because those innocent-looking right joins are not what they seem. My first (incorrect) attempt was this:

```sql
select e.department_id, e.job_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, d.department_name
from   jobs j
     , departments d 
     , employees e
where  e.job_id(+) = j.job_id
and    e.department_id(+) = d.department_id;
```

but as Mathguy points out it gives different results because of the departments with no employees and the cross join between departments and jobs, and a subtle join precedence effect that appears as a result of the right joins not being in one chain.

I'm not sure what the intention of the original query is. Using the Oracle [HR demo schema](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/comsc/installing-sample-schemas.html), the results are the same as an inner join, but only because every job has at least one employee. This illustrates a pitfall in testing outer join queries, as you might run a test, get the same results, and think your rewrite was logically the same thing when it is not.

If you rewrite the original right joins as left joins, it would have to become something like this:

```
select e.department_id, e.job_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, d.department_name
from   jobs j
       left join (
           departments d
           left join employees e on e.department_id = d.department_id
       )
       on e.job_id = j.job_id;
```

(You could also expand the `departments` > `employees` join into an inline view or `with` clause, or use an `outer apply` construction to include the `job_id` join.)

This is because the two right joins in the original query are driven from `jobs` and `departments`, so even though the outer join from `departments` to `employees` includes the 16 departments with no employees, once we outer join from `jobs` to *that*, we implicitly exclude rows with no job_id, because we are driving it from `jobs`. So the outer join to departments is filtered to become in effect an inner join, and so long as all jobs have corresponding employees then that gives the same results as an inner join too. To see the difference you would have to insert another job, which adds a row in the results with the job title but no employee details.

Therefore the old-style version needs to be either this:

```sql
select de.first_name, de.last_name, de.department_name, j.job_title
from   jobs j
     , lateral (
           select e.department_id, e.job_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, d.department_name
           from   departments d
                , employees e
           where  e.department_id(+) = d.department_id
       ) de
where  de.job_id(+) = j.job_id;
```

or without `lateral`:

```sql
select first_name, last_name, department_name, job_title
from   jobs j
     , ( select e.first_name, e.last_name, e.job_id, d.department_name
         from   departments d, employees e
         where  e.department_id (+) = d.department_id ) de
where  de.job_id(+) = j.job_id
```

The second query just switches `jobs` and `departments`:

```sql
select first_name, last_name, department_name, job_title
from   departments d
     , ( select e.first_name, e.last_name, e.department_id, e.job_id, j.job_title
         from   jobs j, employees e
         where  e.job_id(+) = j.job_id ) je
where  je.department_id(+) = d.department_id
```